# webapi response configurable camel or pascal

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have .net core WebApi.

i want consumer to pass in as parameter what kind of casing they want the api to return. eg : say in header if client passes "case" : "camel" my api should return camel casing.

Below code runs on startup and fixes casing to one type during app start.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
     services.AddAbsgLogManagement(Configuration);

     services.AddMvc(config =>{
        .AddJsonOptions(x => {
                x.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
            });
  }
```

Comment: It already *is* configurable. That's what your code does - add the MVC service and configure casing.

Comment: Are you asking aboug something *different* perhaps, like loading the settings from a configuration file or database? It's possible, but why do you think *that* configuration method would be better or *easier*? You'll probably have to make code changes for each client, and keep each client's code in a separate repository. Making the change in code, where it can't be misplaced, is easier than loading the setting from a file.

Comment: Another option is to use camel-case as the default (it *is* the most common naming convention) and allow the *client* to modify the setting from a configuration page. Save the setting in a database (or any other storage) and load it when `ConfigureServices` is called.

Comment: i want consumer to pass in as parameter what kind of casing they want the api to return.  eg : say in header if client passes  "case" : "camel" my api should return camel casing.